# In Ruby, how do I find out if a string is not in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

In Ruby, how would I return true if a string is not in an array of options?

```
# pseudo code
do_this if current_subdomain not_in ["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"]
```

...or do you know of a better way to write this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if variable matches any of several strings w/o long if-elsif chain, or case-when](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893816/test-if-variable-matches-any-of-several-strings-w-o-long-if-elsif-chain-or-case)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
do_this unless  ["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"].include?(current_subdomain)
```

or

```
do_this if not ["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"].include?(current_subdomain)
```

I'm using the [Array#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000265) method.

However using `unless` is a fairly big ruby idiom.

Comment: `do_this if !["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"].include?(current_subdomain)` works. For complex conditions, example one: `&& !` example two: `and not`.

Answer (score 12):

You can try `exclude?` method instead of `include?`

Example:

```
do_this if ["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"].exclude?(current_subdomain)
```

Hope this help...Thanks

Edited: This function is applicable only for Rails (ActiveSupport), not native Ruby.

Comment: exclude? only comes from ActiveSupport library. Not officially supported in core Ruby.

Comment: This function (exclude) is not available in Ruby as of v2.5. You will get a NoMethodError.

Answer (score 4):

Besides using an array, you can also do this:

```
case current_subdomain
when 'www', 'blog', 'foo', 'bar'; do that
else do this
end
```

This is actually much faster:

```
require 'benchmark'
n = 1000000

def answer1 current_subdomain
  case current_subdomain
  when 'www', 'blog', 'foo', 'bar'
  else nil
  end
end

def answer2 current_subdomain
  nil unless  ["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"].include?(current_subdomain)
end

Benchmark.bmbm do |b|
  b.report('answer1'){n.times{answer1('bar')}}
  b.report('answer2'){n.times{answer2('bar')}}
end

Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
answer1   0.290000   0.000000   0.290000 (  0.286367)
answer2   1.170000   0.000000   1.170000 (  1.175492)
---------------------------------- total: 1.460000sec

              user     system      total        real
answer1   0.290000   0.000000   0.290000 (  0.282610)
answer2   1.180000   0.000000   1.180000 (  1.186130)


Benchmark.bmbm do |b|
  b.report('answer1'){n.times{answer1('hello')}}
  b.report('answer2'){n.times{answer2('hello')}}
end

Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
answer1   0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.252618)
answer2   1.100000   0.000000   1.100000 (  1.091571)
---------------------------------- total: 1.350000sec

              user     system      total        real
answer1   0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.251833)
answer2   1.090000   0.000000   1.090000 (  1.090418)
```

Comment: In `answer2`, defining the array `["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"]` as a constant outside the method is faster, but still slower than using `when`.

Answer (score 3):

```
do this if not ["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"].include?(current_subdomain)
```

or you can use `grep`

```
>> d=["www", "blog", "foo", "bar"]
>> d.grep(/^foo$/)
=> ["foo"]
>> d.grep(/abc/)
=> []
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this approach most readable `!'foo'.in?(['bar', 'baz'])`