# ruby match string to array of strings

Tags: ruby, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Ruby, how do I find out if a string is not in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684006/in-ruby-how-do-i-find-out-if-a-string-is-not-in-an-array)

Right now I have this code:

```
partial_update = true if session[:intended_params][:controller] == 'foo'
partial_update = true if session[:intended_params][:controller] == 'bar'
partial_update = true if session[:intended_params][:controller] == 'ding'
partial_update = true if session[:intended_params][:controller] == 'dong'
partial_update = true if session[:intended_params][:controller] == 'up'
partial_update = true if session[:intended_params][:controller] == 'down'
partial_update = true if session[:intended_params][:controller] == 'bing'
# ETC.
```

I would like to change this to

```
array = %w[foo bar ding dong up down bing]
partial_update = true if session[:intended_params][:controller]  == array.any_of_the_possibilites
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Ruby [Array (Enumerable) `include?` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F):

```ruby
array = %w[foo bar ding dong up down bing]
partial_update = true if array.include?(session[:intended_params][:controller])
```

Comment: not exactly equivalent to what OP expected as it will assign `false` if none match (not saying original behavior is right)

Comment: @VictorMoroz: ah, true, i'll modify slightly.

Answer (score 1):

```
case session[:intended_params][:controller]
when *%w[foo bar ding dong up down bing]
  partial_update =  true
end
```

might be abusing `case` statement though